# tomcat server response after continuous interval?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want in my j2me application that a server check a table in database and send response to the application after some interval. I am using Tomcat as server. 
Any suggestion how and what way I will implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want tomcat to take initiative to send a response after specific time interval?
Are you using Ajax in application. What you can do is in your application, at client side run a thread which can make a request to tomcat after a specific time interval and get a response.

Comment: @user180152 yes.i am making a application for j2me user in which a servlet will check that connect to the database and looking in a column.
when there is new entry(like message)then server will send a response to the servlet. if it send the response to the servlet then i can show it on my j2me application